# Pass back an id for a new record in another model to the controller

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am creating a small and simple warehouse application (for assets). I want to log all operations so I made an afterSave method in Asset model.

This method imports the Log model and create an entry in it based on the datas have been sent.
Works quite fine :)

For visual feedback to the user I would like to display the ID of the new log entry, so I need to send it back to the controller.
I googled around a lot but did not find anything to help me how to start it at all.

How to pass back this new ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could save the id in the model itself and retrieve it from there.

Model:

```
var $logId = 0;

function afterSave( $created ) {
    // data saving code

    $this->logId = $this->Log->getInsertId();
}
```

Controller:

```
$this->Asset->save( $this->data );
$this->set( 'logId', $this->Asset->logId );
```